# How to create an animation in a QtGui?

Tags: python, animation, pyqt, pyqt4, qgraphicsview

I'm fairly new to Python and Qt, but I'm trying to create a GUI with some animated graphic elements. I can make a simple animation work; in the following code `class MyView` will work when called, but `class GraphicsView` is not animated!

Can anyone help me see the problem?

The problem is in the class GraphicsScene, I think:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)

        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.item = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(-20, -10, 40, 20)
        self.scene.addItem(self.item)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        # Remember to hold the references to QTimeLine and QGraphicsItemAnimation instances.
        # They are not kept anywhere, even if you invoke QTimeLine.start().
        self.tl = QtCore.QTimeLine(1000)
        self.tl.setFrameRange(0, 100)
        self.a = QtGui.QGraphicsItemAnimation()
        self.a.setItem(self.item)
        self.a.setTimeLine(self.tl)

        # Each method determining an animation state (e.g. setPosAt, setRotationAt etc.)
        # takes as a first argument a step which is a value between 0 (the beginning of the
        # animation) and 1 (the end of the animation)
        self.a.setPosAt(0, QtCore.QPointF(0, -10))
        self.a.setRotationAt(1, 360)

        self.tl.start()

#create the graphicsView which contains the graphicsScene
class GraphicsView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    #initialize and set dragMode and renderHints for everything inside the view
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)

        #the dragMode should be changed to use the rihgt-mousebutton
        self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.TextAntialiasing)

    #crate a zoom function for the mouse-wheel
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        factor = 1.5 ** (event.delta() / 240.0)
        self.scale(factor, factor)

#create the GraphicsScene containing the main graphics
class GraphicsScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):

    def animate(self):

        self.animations = range(3)

        #move item to position(x,y) at time t
        def animate_to(item,x,y,t):

            animation = QtGui.QGraphicsItemAnimation()
            #create a timeline of 1 second
            timeline = QtCore.QTimeLine(2000)
            #number of steps in timeline (100)
            timeline.setFrameRange(0,100)
            #set position at time t
            animation.setPosAt(t, QtCore.QPointF(x,y))
            #apply this to "item"
            animation.setItem(item)
            #add timeline to the animation
            animation.setTimeLine(timeline)

            #output of this definition is "animation"
            return animation

        self.animations[0] = animate_to(self.geos[0],200,200,0.2)
        self.animations[1] = animate_to(self.geos[1],200,200,0.2)
        self.animations[2] = animate_to(self.geos[2],200,200,0.2)

        #animation.timeline().start()
        self.animator.start(2000)


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, parent)
        #set the size of the scene
        self.setSceneRect(0,0,2000,2000)

        #self.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(800,800,200,200))

        #---create the scene-geometries ---   

        #empty list to hold the geometries
        self.geos = []

        #create stuff to add to the scene
        geo_01 = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(800,800,200,200)
        geo_02 = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(850,850,300,300)
        geo_03 = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(900,900,400,400)
        #add stuff to the scene
        self.addItem(geo_01)
        self.addItem(geo_02)
        self.addItem(geo_03)

        #put stuff into list so it can be referenced
        self.geos.append(geo_01)
        self.geos.append(geo_02)
        self.geos.append(geo_03)

        #----do the animation thing---
        self.animator = QtCore.QTimer()

        self.animator.timeout.connect(self.animate)

        self.animate()


#Create a new class which inherrits from "QtGui.QMainWindow"
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        #The "super()"-method returns the parrent object of the example-class
        #and it's constructor is called ("__init__")
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    #create the GUI
    def initUI(self):

        """---create the buttons---"""

        #set a font for the tool-tips
        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))

        #create a button and a tool-tip for the button
        btn_01 = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn_01.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        #resize the button with a recommended size (.sizeHint())
        btn_01.resize(btn_01.sizeHint())

        #create a button and a tool-tip for the button
        btn_02 = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn_02.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        #resize the button with a recommended size (.sizeHint())
        btn_02.resize(btn_02.sizeHint())

        """----create a layout----"""

        #create the main widget, which holds the layout
        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)

        #create a vertical box layout to hold the buttons on the right
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addWidget(btn_01)
        vbox.addWidget(btn_02)  

        #create horizontal box layout to hold the vbox and the main area
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        #store the GraphicsScene in a variable so it is not destroyed
        self.scene = GraphicsScene()
        #add the scene to the GraphicsView
        view = GraphicsView(self.scene)

        hbox.addWidget(view)
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addLayout(vbox)

        self.main_widget.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        #set the possition and size of the window, then set the window title
        #these methods have been inherited by the "QtGui.QWidget"-class
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 700, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("PatternNexus...Maybe?")
        #self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('web.png'))

        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        #create a messagebox to confirm quit
        # when QtGui.QWidget is closed the QtGui.QCloseEvent is generated
        # to modify its behaviour the event handler (closeEvent()) must be reinplemented

        #create a msgBox with 2 buttons
        #4th argument is the button combination
        #5th argument is the button with initial ketboard focus
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you leaving?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | 
            QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        #test the return value, is "yes" the event is accepted
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

def main():
    #start the application
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

#if this module (.py-file) is run as the main program the statement is true
#if this module is imported the statement will return false
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My main references for coding this are "Rapid GUI programming with python and QT - Chapter 12", and these links: http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/stories/BBS53.html, and http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/GraphicsView_-_SimpleAnimation

Comment: It's somewhat difficult to go through that length of code to find the specific error. One thing you could try to debug this is to add some print statements (or, perhaps better, some logging statements) throughout your code and see what is being executed and what isn't. After that, you may have already found the answer, or you could re-edit your question such that it has a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) and others can help you from there.

Comment: thanks for the pointers Jeff - I managed to find the problem: in the animate def I am not starting the timeline. I need to add: [ animation.timeLine().start() for animation in self.animations ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the answer to my question was: start the timelne by adding:
[ animation.timeLine().start() for animation in self.animations ]
in the animate definition

Comment: Adding your answer (`[animation.timeLine.start() for animation in self.animations`) I get the error `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'start'`